NextJS Warning: "Extra attributes from the server: data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded... "
Have a problem in console
Warning: Extra attributes from the server: data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded,data-gr-ext-installed at body at html and blah-blah
The solution helped me
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
            <body className={inter.className} suppressHydrationWarning>{children}</body>
        </html>
    );
}


Does this answer your question? What causes NextJS Warning: "Extra attributes from the server: data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded... "

I was getting started with next.js and saw this warning.
The browser Console showed this message every time a page was loaded:

Warning: Extra attributes from the server: cz-shortcut-listen

Thanks to your solution, I added suppressHydrationWarning to the body in layout.js, and it stopped showing that warning.
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang='en'>
            <body suppressHydrationWarning>
                {children}
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}

